# How do I programmatically jump from a cross reference target bookmark to the related cross reference source field in a Word document?

Tags: .net, vb.net, ms-word, office-interop, office-addins

I have a VSTO add-in for Word. I am trying to write code that the user will execute when the cursor is in a paragraph containing a cross reference target bookmark, and which will jump the cursor to the paragraph containing the related cross reference source field.

I have made such cross reference target bookmarks visible in all my documents. (To do this, I changed _Ref to XRef in the underlying XML.) So, when I scroll through one of my documents, I can see visible bookmarks that indicate that the paragraph is the target of a cross-reference. I would execute such above described code in a paragraph that contains such a bookmark.

I know that to use code to jump in the other direction (i.e., from the source to the target), you need the bookmark name, say "XRef130657095" , and then you could do, e.g. ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("XRef130657095").Select . However, I cannot work out if it is possible to jump in the other direction.

If it is not possible via bookmarks, maybe the following will help with an alternative approach: I use numbered paragraphs throughout all of my documents. If I could identify the long paragraph number (e.g., 17.A.3.d) that is at the target bookmark location, that could help me solve this, because the cross-reference contains that number, so I could search for that number and jump to it?

Many thanks!

Comment: Hi, this is a programming forum, not a Word forum. Your question is ***off-topic*** here and likely will be closed without answers. The confusion is understandable. https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic  This would be an appropriate question on the **Microsoft Community** https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word  or on **Super User** https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-word or other forums. If you do post something there, you should delete this question or at least add a link in your question here to the new question there to help others. --- Try Alt+ <--

Comment: Hello Charles, I am very much asking a programming question. I have a Word add-in built with VSTO. The intention is that the user clicks in a paragraph that starts with a bookmark that is the target of a cross-reference, and then clicks a Word add-in ribbon button, then the code ascertains the source cross-reference location and jumps to it. A Word power user will very likely not be able to answer this, because it requires programmatic usage of the Word object model. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Also, I don't even know if what I am trying to do is possible with the Word object model, but maybe there is a brute force programming technique I can use.

Comment: @jonsson - Thanks for taking the time to suggest improvements. I have redrafted both the question and details. And yes, you are correct; that is exactly what I am trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use something like the following. Bear in mind that there can be multiple bookmarks in a paragraph, and that there can be multiple  references to any given bookmark. Maybe you know exactly what you want to do, but here, I've just selected the first reference I can find to any of the bookmarks in the paragraph that start with "_ref" and displayed a message if there were no such bookmarks or there are other references to any of them. I have only iterated the fields in the main storyrange, not other ranges such as textboxes and so on.

```
Option Explicit
Sub gotoreverseref1()
Dim bm As Word.Bookmark
Dim f As Word.Field
Dim i As Long
Dim bookmarkCount As Long
Dim bookmarkName As String
Dim refFound As Boolean
Dim refFoundCount As Long
Dim sh As Boolean

refFound = False
refFoundCount = 0
With Selection.Paragraphs(1).Range
  ' save the .SHowhidden state and
  ' ensure we can find the bookmarks
  sh = .Bookmarks.ShowHidden
  .Bookmarks.ShowHidden = True
  bookmarkCount = .Bookmarks.Count
  For Each bm In .Bookmarks
    ' You don't have to constrain the search in this way
    If UCase(Left(bm.Name, 4)) = "_REF" Then
      bookmarkName = bm.Name
      For Each f In ActiveDocument.Fields
        If f.Type = wdFieldRef Then
          If InStr(UCase(f.Code.Text), UCase(bookmarkName)) > 0 Then
            If Not refFound Then
              f.Select
              refFound = True
            End If
            refFoundCount = refFoundCount + 1
          End If
        End If
      Next
    End If
  Next
  .Bookmarks.ShowHidden = sh
End With
If bookmarkCount = 0 Then
  MsgBox "The selected paragraph did not contain any _ref bookmarks."
Else
  If refFound Then
    If refFoundCount > 1 Then
      MsgBox "A reference found and selected. There are " & CStr(refFoundCount) & " references to _ref bookmarks in the selected paragraph."
    End If ' no message if only one ref found
  Else
    If bookmarkCount = 1 Then
      MsgBox "There is 1 _ref bookmark in the selected paragraph but no references to it were found."
    Else
      MsgBox "There are " & CStr(bookmarkCount) & " _ref bookmarks in the selected paragraph but no references to them were found."
    End If
  End If
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your help! You helped me crack a problem that I was having quite a bit of difficulty with. 

The key line is:  If InStr(UCase(f.Code.Text), UCase(bookmarkName)) > 0 Then

I will provide my vb.net solution just below.

Answer (score 0):

This is my implementation of @jonsson's correct answer:

```
Private Shared Sub T_S_ProcessMid(ByVal V_V_1_Selection_Generic As Selection)
    With V_V_1_Selection_Generic.Paragraphs(1).Range
        .Bookmarks.ShowHidden = True
        Dim L_V_N_Bookmark_GenericLoopSet As Bookmarks = .Bookmarks
        Dim L_V_1_Boolean_FieldReferencingBookmarkIsFound As Boolean
        Dim L_V_1_Integer_FieldsReferencingBookmarkQuantityCardinal As Integer = 0
        For Each L_V_1_Bookmark_GenericLoopItem As Bookmark In L_V_N_Bookmark_GenericLoopSet
            Dim L_V_1_String_BookmarkNameInUpperCase As String = L_V_1_Bookmark_GenericLoopItem.Name.ToUpper
            Dim L_V_1_String_BookmarkNameInUpperCaseInitialCharacters As String = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Left(L_V_1_String_BookmarkNameInUpperCase, "XREF".Length)
            Dim L_V_1_Boolean_BookmarkRelatesToACrossReference As Boolean = (L_V_1_String_BookmarkNameInUpperCaseInitialCharacters = "XREF")
            If L_V_1_Boolean_BookmarkRelatesToACrossReference Then

                Dim L_V_N_Field_GenericLoopSet As Fields = V_V_1_Selection_Generic.Document.Fields
                For Each L_V_1_Field_GenericLoopItem As Field In L_V_N_Field_GenericLoopSet
                    Dim L_V_1_String_FieldCodeTextInUpperCase As String = L_V_1_Field_GenericLoopItem.Code.Text.ToUpper
                    If _
                        (L_V_1_Field_GenericLoopItem.Type = WdFieldType.wdFieldRef) AndAlso
                        L_V_1_String_FieldCodeTextInUpperCase.Contains(L_V_1_String_BookmarkNameInUpperCase) Then
                        L_V_1_Integer_FieldsReferencingBookmarkQuantityCardinal += 1
                        If Not L_V_1_Boolean_FieldReferencingBookmarkIsFound Then
                            L_V_1_Field_GenericLoopItem.Select()
                            L_V_1_Boolean_FieldReferencingBookmarkIsFound = True
                        End If
                    End If
                Next
            End If
        Next
        If L_V_1_Integer_FieldsReferencingBookmarkQuantityCardinal > 1 Then
            C_N_H_CoreCommonCore.U_C_U_LoggingAndDisplaying.P_S_LogThenDisplayMessageInformation($"This bookmark has {L_V_1_Integer_FieldsReferencingBookmarkQuantityCardinal} references.")
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```